# NGINX module to edit request body

Tags: nginx, nginx-module

I am trying to create an NGINX module to inject a property into the request body (all the requests are JSON formated) to be sent to the upstream. The idea is to validate the bearer authentication token, get a property from the token and inject it into the request body to be used by the backend.
The authentication is working fine and I was able to find a way to manipulate the body for smaller requests (but I don't know if I am doing it correctly, please correct me if I am wrong). But when the request is quite large, the code doesn't work and also locks the request.

here is the code I have written so far:

```
static ngx_int_t ngx_http_user_auth_handler(ngx_http_request_t *r){
// ...

    ngx_int_t  rc;
    rc = ngx_http_read_client_request_body(r, ProcessBodyRequest);

    return rc;

// ...
}

static void ProcessBodyRequest(ngx_http_request_t  *r){

    ngx_log_error(NGX_LOG_DEBUG, r->connection->log, 0, "Test: starting body processing ");

    ngx_str_t randomstr = ngx_string("{\"foo\":\"bar\"}");
    u_char *new_body = ngx_pcalloc(r->pool,randomstr.len+1);
    ngx_memcpy(new_body,randomstr.data,randomstr.len);


    ngx_buf_t *b;
    b = ngx_create_temp_buf(r->pool,randomstr.len);

    b->last = (u_char*)ngx_cpymem(b->pos, randomstr.data, randomstr.len);

    r->request_body->bufs[0].buf = b;
    r->headers_in.content_length_n = randomstr.len;

    ngx_http_finalize_request(r, NGX_DONE);

}
```

That is my NGINX conf:

```
location /api {
        proxy_pass http://dataserver;
        rewrite ^/api/(\w+)/([\w\/]+)?(\.*) /test-$1-api/$1/$2?$3 break;
        auth_jwt session; #off | jwks | session
    }
```

And here is the log:

```
2022/01/27 10:48:02 [debug] 9997#9997: notify eventfd: 17
2022/01/27 10:48:02 [debug] 9997#9997: testing the EPOLLRDHUP flag: success
2022/01/27 10:48:02 [debug] 9997#9997: malloc: 000056025842E4A0:6144
2022/01/27 10:48:02 [debug] 9997#9997: malloc: 0000560258475520:178176
2022/01/27 10:48:02 [debug] 9997#9997: malloc: 00005602584A0D30:73728
2022/01/27 10:48:02 [debug] 9997#9997: malloc: 00005602584B2D40:73728
2022/01/27 10:48:02 [debug] 9997#9997: epoll add event: fd:15 op:1 ev:00002001
2022/01/27 10:48:02 [debug] 9997#9997: setproctitle: "nginx: worker process"
2022/01/27 10:48:02 [debug] 9997#9997: worker cycle
2022/01/27 10:48:02 [debug] 9997#9997: epoll timer: -1
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: epoll: fd:8 ev:0001 d:0000560258475608
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: timer delta: 3230
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: worker cycle
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: epoll timer: 60000
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: epoll: fd:8 ev:0001 d:0000560258475608
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: timer delta: 0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: worker cycle
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: epoll timer: 60000
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: epoll: fd:14 ev:2001 d:00005602584757D8
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: epoll: fd:15 ev:0001 d:00005602584758C0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http header: "Host: localhost"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http header: "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http header: "Connection: keep-alive"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http header: "Content-Length: 23594"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http header: "Cookie: AUTH_SESSION_ID=8e46b1ef-2161-4a03-ae46-46c286787192.8e2f215841be; AUTH_SESSION_ID_LEGACY=8e46b1ef-2161-4a03-ae46-46c286787192.8e2f215841be; KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICI1ZGM1NmQ2ZS00NDQwLTQ4NmMtODU3Zi05ODI1NzVlYmEyMTYifQ.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.7LgYGRD7WF-TBk8A-CY9ymk-pVqEZtLa5NMhHPPc7No; KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY_LEGACY=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICI1ZGM1NmQ2ZS00NDQwLTQ4NmMtODU3Zi05ODI1NzVlYmEyMTYifQ.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.7LgYGRD7WF-TBk8A-CY9ymk-pVqEZtLa5NMhHPPc7No; KEYCLOAK_SESSION=Paragon/f:6294a860-354f-4362-ad11-7adee39366ec:admin@test.com/8e46b1ef-2161-4a03-ae46-46c286787192; KEYCLOAK_SESSION_LEGACY=Paragon/f:6294a860-354f-4362-ad11-7adee39366ec:admin@test.com/8e46b1ef-2161-4a03-ae46-46c286787192"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http header done
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 event timer del: 15: 71532470
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 generic phase: 0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 rewrite phase: 1
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 test location: "/"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 test location: "50x.html"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 using configuration "/"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http cl:23594 max:1048576
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 rewrite phase: 3
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 post rewrite phase: 4
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 generic phase: 5
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 generic phase: 6
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 generic phase: 7
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 access phase: 8
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http client request body preread 4806
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http request body content length filter
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http body new buf t:1 f:0 0000560258404F0A, pos 0000560258404F0A, size: 4806 file: 0, size: 0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 malloc: 00005602584C4D50:8192
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http read client request body
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 recv: eof:0, avail:18788
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 recv: fd:15 8192 of 8192
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 recv: avail:10596
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http client request body recv 8192
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http body new buf t:1 f:0 00005602584C4D50, pos 00005602584C4D50, size: 8192 file: 0, size: 0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http write client request body, bufs 0000560258442910
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 add cleanup: 0000560258442A10
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 hashed path: /var/lib/nginx/body/0000000001
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 temp fd:14
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [warn] 9995#9995: *2 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /var/lib/nginx/body/0000000001, client: ::1, server: localhost, request: "POST /test HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 writev: 14, 12998, 0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 recv: eof:0, avail:10596
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 recv: fd:15 8192 of 8192
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 recv: avail:2404
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http client request body recv 8192
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http body new buf t:1 f:0 00005602584C4D50, pos 00005602584C4D50, size: 8192 file: 0, size: 0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http write client request body, bufs 00005602584429E0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 write: 14, 00005602584C4D50, 8192, 12998
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 recv: eof:0, avail:2404
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 recv: fd:15 2404 of 2404
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 recv: avail:0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http client request body recv 2404
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http body new buf t:1 f:0 00005602584C4D50, pos 00005602584C4D50, size: 2404 file: 0, size: 0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http write client request body, bufs 00005602584429E0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 write: 14, 00005602584C4D50, 2404, 21190
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http client request body rest 0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 Test: starting body processing 
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http finalize request: -4, "/test?" a:1, c:2
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http request count:2 blk:0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 access phase: 9
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 access phase: 10
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 access phase: 11
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 post access phase: 12
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 generic phase: 13
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 generic phase: 14
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http init upstream, client timer: 0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 epoll add event: fd:15 op:3 ev:80002005
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 posix_memalign: 00005602584061E0:4096 @16
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http script copy: "Host"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http script var: "localhost"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http script copy: "X-Forwarded-For"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http script var: "::1"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http script copy: "Connection"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http script copy: "close"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http script copy: "Content-Length"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http script var: "13"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http script copy: ""
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http proxy header: "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICI5dHl2Qi1fWEdFZ1hMVkxkUFMxLUZ6Qks1TThPYTB0aE03ckt4RXE4cDNVIn0.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.ZdVGiQt_GneokfNvXREs0Q1pUGi3wPytlZV4o19hnrUb_X1S6QM6d-FeC7rkN7QSJk6VsD6GPs57mRZ2cKZSFg_Oefa3vZR2VzHDqIc3oJR3bbYxTEdxIycqbYJueUok1lolY2GVP7zvKfKD8b-0m4V4FVFUPaGEkzRt7ahmo2qpiicbDvlRIpdA0ZByrrVe-CFnpAzeaqUVjeclcuq39lulCY63YRkN-pNFlMAOsYplrdJ1vX91u-TZLZ8NaPe7lx4jVpT-rpaVHz5Quecg5OmgTVt9GK21KUgcKLUmNEAdQzmDii75oGKCix3cEqi-VI01_hTeitGDUMtEKOArjA"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http proxy header: "Content-Type: application/json"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http proxy header: "User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http proxy header: "Accept: */*"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http proxy header: "Postman-Token: 9d11dd75-1808-4038-830a-7a95b31e1944"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http proxy header: "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http proxy header: "Cookie: AUTH_SESSION_ID=8e46b1ef-2161-4a03-ae46-46c286787192.8e2f215841be; AUTH_SESSION_ID_LEGACY=8e46b1ef-2161-4a03-ae46-46c286787192.8e2f215841be; KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICI1ZGM1NmQ2ZS00NDQwLTQ4NmMtODU3Zi05ODI1NzVlYmEyMTYifQ.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.7LgYGRD7WF-TBk8A-CY9ymk-pVqEZtLa5NMhHPPc7No; KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY_LEGACY=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICI1ZGM1NmQ2ZS00NDQwLTQ4NmMtODU3Zi05ODI1NzVlYmEyMTYifQ.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.7LgYGRD7WF-TBk8A-CY9ymk-pVqEZtLa5NMhHPPc7No; KEYCLOAK_SESSION=Paragon/f:6294a860-354f-4362-ad11-7adee39366ec:admin@test.com/8e46b1ef-2161-4a03-ae46-46c286787192; KEYCLOAK_SESSION_LEGACY=Paragon/f:6294a860-354f-4362-ad11-7adee39366ec:admin@test.com/8e46b1ef-2161-4a03-ae46-46c286787192"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http proxy header:
"POST /test HTTP/1.0
Host: localhost
X-Forwarded-For: ::1
Connection: close
Content-Length: 13
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICI5dHl2Qi1fWEdFZ1hMVkxkUFMxLUZ6Qks1TThPYTB0aE03ckt4RXE4cDNVIn0.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.ZdVGiQt_GneokfNvXREs0Q1pUGi3wPytlZV4o19hnrUb_X1S6QM6d-FeC7rkN7QSJk6VsD6GPs57mRZ2cKZSFg_Oefa3vZR2VzHDqIc3oJR3bbYxTEdxIycqbYJueUok1lolY2GVP7zvKfKD8b-0m4V4FVFUPaGEkzRt7ahmo2qpiicbDvlRIpdA0ZByrrVe-CFnpAzeaqUVjeclcuq39lulCY63YRkN-pNFlMAOsYplrdJ1vX91u-TZLZ8NaPe7lx4jVpT-rpaVHz5Quecg5OmgTVt9GK21KUgcKLUmNEAdQzmDii75oGKCix3cEqi-VI01_hTeitGDUMtEKOArjA
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 9d11dd75-1808-4038-830a-7a95b31e1944
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Cookie: AUTH_SESSION_ID=8e46b1ef-2161-4a03-ae46-46c286787192.8e2f215841be; AUTH_SESSION_ID_LEGACY=8e46b1ef-2161-4a03-ae46-46c286787192.8e2f215841be; KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICI1ZGM1NmQ2ZS00NDQwLTQ4NmMtODU3Zi05ODI1NzVlYmEyMTYifQ.eyJleHAiOjE2NDE4Nzc0MTAsImlhdCI6MTY0MTg0MTQxMCwianRpIjoiMWIzYTQ4N
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http cleanup add: 0000560258430978
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 get rr peer, try: 1
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 stream socket 16
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 epoll add connection: fd:16 ev:80002005
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 connect to 127.0.0.1:1080, fd:16 #3
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http upstream connect: -2
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 posix_memalign: 00005602583DE6C0:128 @16
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 event timer add: 16: 60000:71532490
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http finalize request: -4, "/test?" a:1, c:2
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http request count:2 blk:0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: timer delta: 20
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: worker cycle
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: epoll timer: 60000
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: epoll: fd:15 ev:0004 d:00005602584758C0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http run request: "/test?"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http upstream check client, write event:1, "/test"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: epoll: fd:16 ev:0004 d:00005602584757D9
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http upstream request: "/test?"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http upstream send request handler
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http upstream send request
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http upstream send request body
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 chain writer buf fl:0 s:3421
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 chain writer buf fl:1 s:13
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 chain writer in: 00005602584309D8
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 writev: 3434 of 3434
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 chain writer out: 0000000000000000
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 event timer del: 16: 71532490
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 event timer add: 16: 60000:71532490
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: timer delta: 0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: worker cycle
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: epoll timer: 60000
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: epoll: fd:16 ev:0005 d:00005602584757D9
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http upstream request: "/test?"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http upstream process header
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 malloc: 00005602584C6D60:4096
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 recv: eof:0, avail:-1
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 recv: fd:16 64 of 4096
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http proxy status 404 "404 Not Found"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http proxy header: "connection: close"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http proxy header: "content-length: 0"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http proxy header done
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 xslt filter header
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Thu, 27 Jan 2022 13:48:05 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive

2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 write new buf t:1 f:0 0000560258406F60, pos 0000560258406F60, size: 137 file: 0, size: 0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http write filter: l:0 f:0 s:137
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 file cleanup: fd:14
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http cacheable: 0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http proxy filter init s:404 h:0 c:0 l:0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http upstream process upstream
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 pipe read upstream: 0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 pipe preread: 0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 pipe buf free s:0 t:1 f:0 00005602584C6D60, pos 00005602584C6DA0, size: 0 file: 0, size: 0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 pipe length: 0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 pipe write downstream: 1
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 pipe write downstream done
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 event timer: 16, old: 71532490, new: 71532530
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http upstream exit: 0000000000000000
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 finalize http upstream request: 0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 finalize http proxy request
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 free rr peer 1 0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 close http upstream connection: 16
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 free: 00005602583DE6C0, unused: 48
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 event timer del: 16: 71532490
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 reusable connection: 0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http upstream temp fd: -1
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http output filter "/test?"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http copy filter: "/test?"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 posix_memalign: 00005602584C7D70:4096 @16
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 image filter
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 xslt filter body
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http postpone filter "/test?" 00007FFFA5FCA050
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 write old buf t:1 f:0 0000560258406F60, pos 0000560258406F60, size: 137 file: 0, size: 0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 0000000000000000, size: 0 file: 0, size: 0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http write filter: l:1 f:0 s:137
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http write filter limit 0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 writev: 137 of 137
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http write filter 0000000000000000
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http copy filter: 0 "/test?"
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http finalize request: 0, "/test?" a:1, c:1
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 set http keepalive handler
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http close request
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http log handler
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 free: 00005602584C6D60
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 free: 00005602584C4D50
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 free: 0000560258441A70, unused: 0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 free: 000056025842FCB0, unused: 48
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 free: 00005602584061E0, unused: 120
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 free: 00005602584C7D70, unused: 3799
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 free: 00005602583E4540
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 hc free: 0000000000000000
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 hc busy: 00005602583FE490 1
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 free: 00005602584041D0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 tcp_nodelay
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 reusable connection: 1
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 event timer add: 15: 65000:71537530
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 post event 00005602584A0EB0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: timer delta: 40
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: posted event 00005602584A0EB0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 delete posted event 00005602584A0EB0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 http keepalive handler
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 malloc: 00005602583E4540:1024
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 recv: eof:0, avail:0
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: *2 free: 00005602583E4540
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: worker cycle
2022/01/27 10:48:05 [debug] 9995#9995: epoll timer: 65000
```

Could you guys please help me to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?, I'm stuck on the same issue

Comment: @Shedrack yes I found it! I will create a repo containing the solution and post it here to anyone that might need it.

Comment: Okay, it will be helpful